# Can't connect to FTP with basic auth

Tags: iis, ftp, authentication

We cloned a machine and are trying to set up our FTP server on a new domain.  The FTP server is very basic.  It is set up to allow basic auth, no anonymous, and allows read and write to all users to the directory location.  We created a user to access this the same as we had on the old domain.

When I try to access this FTP server though I get an authentication window and neither the user account we created for use with this or even my own domain admin account can access it.  It keeps giving me an access denied error.

When I try to connect to the old FTP server (that this new machine is a clone of) I get the authentication menu but when entering in the user that accessed that FTP directory on the old domain it connects just fine.

I appear to be connecting to the server so I don't think there is any network or firewall issue.  But since authentication is working on the old server and not on this one, not even with a domain admin account, there appears to be some permission or setting I need to grant to an account missing.  Any ideas?

Comment: Also when I try to connect to the old FTP server with my domain admin account on that domain I also get access denied.  So there is some specific setting or permission granted just to this one account and I'm not sure what it is or where to find it.

Comment: What do your logs say?

Comment: Nothing at all.  On either the FTP server or the server I'm connecting from.

Comment: Are you using IIS FTP server?

Comment: Same problem with IIS FTP on Windows 7 unless I am missing something. It does not report failed FTP authentications. If you can't find a way to get that info, you may want to consider a 3rd party FTP server. It seems like a security risk.

Comment: It is IIS FTP but that's what we have, I don't really have the option to go with a third party like.  It seems like there has to be some really simple setting I'm missing though, because this account specifically on the old server works even though a domain admin doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working by changing the FTP user isolation settings in IIS.  It was set to use user isolation (which I'm still unsure why this worked on the old domain but not on the new one) and once I changed this to direct connections to the ftp root I no longer had any issues.